# What does this traceback error mean when running this python script in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

New to programming. Installed Anaconda on a Windows 10 machine. Had some issues running updates.

While in Base environment, I installed my first Git repo successfully:

```
(base) C:\Users\samsung\Anaconda3\pkgs>pip install git+git://github.com/json-transformations/jsonflatten.git
Collecting git+git://github.com/json-transformations/jsonflatten.git
  Cloning git://github.com/json-transformations/jsonflatten.git to c:\users\samsung\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-zeiezw
  Running command git clone -q git://github.com/json-transformations/jsonflatten.git 'C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Local\Temp\p
Collecting jsoncut
  Downloading jsoncut-0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=6.0 in c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jsonflatten==0.2) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jsoncut->jsonflatten==0.2) (0
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jsoncut->jsonflatten==0.2) (2
Building wheels for collected packages: jsonflatten
  Building wheel for jsonflatten (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for jsonflatten: filename=jsonflatten-0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=8116 sha256=029aafde944303cbfe872e86a13
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-so8173tt\wheels\8f\02\52\37295acfd1368a3d2
Successfully built jsonflatten
Installing collected packages: jsoncut, jsonflatten
Successfully installed jsoncut-0.6 jsonflatten-0.2

(base) C:\Users\samsung\Anaconda3\pkgs>pip install jsonflatten
Requirement already satisfied: jsonflatten in c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=6.0 in c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jsonflatten) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jsoncut in c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jsonflatten) (0.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jsoncut->jsonflatten) (2.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jsoncut->jsonflatten) (0.4.3)
```

I then ran jsonflatten forecast.json as a test (as well as jsonflatten C:\Users\samsung.spyder-py3\forecast.json) as the readme suggests and got the output below. I ran from base as myenv (Python) spit out a message saying jsonflatten is not recognized as a command.

```
(base) C:\Users\samsung\.spyder-py3>jsonflatten C:\Users\samsung\.spyder-py3\forecast.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\samsung\Anaconda3\Scripts\jsonflatten.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonflatten\cli.py", line 63, in main
    output(ctx, results, indent=4, is_json=True)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsoncut\cli.py", line 59, in output
    output = highlighter.highlight_json(output)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsoncut\highlighter.py", line 53, in highlight_json
    return pygments.highlight(d, JsonLexer(), formatter)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygments\__init__.py", line 85, in highlight
    return format(lex(code, lexer), formatter, outfile)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygments\__init__.py", line 64, in format
    formatter.format(tokens, realoutfile)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygments\formatters\terminal.py", line 101, in format
    return Formatter.format(self, tokensource, outfile)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygments\formatter.py", line 95, in format
    return self.format_unencoded(tokensource, outfile)
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygments\formatters\terminal.py", line 126, in format_unencoded
    outfile.write(ansiformat(color, line.rstrip('\n')))
  File "c:\users\samsung\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pygments\console.py", line 68, in ansiformat
    result.append(codes[attr])
KeyError: 'darkgray'
```

There is a guide for troubleshooting software in Anaconda: https://www.anaconda.com/what-to-do-when-things-go-wrong-in-anaconda/ but this is a brand-new install.

Does this look like an Anaconda issue, an issue with how I am running the software or an issue with the software itself?

Comment: It means there's no `codes['darkgrey']`

Comment: It means `jsonflatten` doesn't have good test coverage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an error in `site-packages` with a module that is a dependency of something that you've installed.

Anaconda is just a distribtion, not the runtime.

The problem is from Python's `pygments\console.py` module, which is likely responsible for coloring the output of your `jsonflatten` module.

Try to see if there is a CLI flag to not colorize stuff, or don't use `jsonflatten` and rather use python's `json.tool` or separately install `jq` instead. (not saying those offer what you need, but they also parse JSON on the CLI)

Comment: [jsonflatten](https://pypi.org/project/jsonflatten/) has an option `-n, --nocolor`

Comment: Using the -n option fixed it